# Sound card not detected (Dummy Output only) on Dell XPS 13 9350

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, xps

My Dell XPS 13 9350 laptop came with Ubuntu 14.04 installed and I had
never had sound issues.  Since an upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 the laptop has
produced no sound so I've tried applying various fixes found online,
possibly messing up more things.

- In the graphical interface, in the "Settings > Sound > Output" the
  only available device is *Dummy Output*.  The same *Dummy Ouput* name
  appears when I change volume through F-keys.
- `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload` unloads ALSA sound drivers
  then reloads them but this does not restore sound.
- `pacmd list-cards` gives `0 card(s) available.`

## About ALSA

On the other hand, `aplay -l` finds a sound card whose number matches
the "Audio controller" `RealTek ALC3246` listed in the BIOS:

```
$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3246 Analog [ALC3246 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$ grep "Codec:" /proc/asound/card*/codec*
Codec: Realtek ALC3246
```

This is consistent with the behaviour of `alsamixer`, which shows
Realtex ALC3246 and a bunch of gauges I can vary, with no effect.

Since all seems normal for ALSA, I tried bypassing `pulseaudio`.  First, `speaker-test` does not produce any sound.  Next I tried

```
aplay -D sysdefault ~/Downloads/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav
```

without success.  With the `-vvv` option I can see an indicator bar
showing the volume varying along the music; still no sound.  Repeating
the experiment with pulseaudio uninstalled
(`sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio`) does not help.

## lsof, ps and lsmod

`lsof /dev/snd/*` gives no output at all (but as per `ls` the directory `/dev/snd` contains:
`by-path  controlC0  hwC0D0  pcmC0D0c  pcmC0D0p  seq  timer`).

```
$ ps -ef | grep pulse
gdm       2168  1827  0 19:53 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
bruno     2555     1  0 19:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
bruno     4106  3923  0 20:11 pts/2    00:00:00 grep --color=auto pulse

$ lsmod | grep snd
snd_soc_skl           106496  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       28672  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_skl_ipc        65536  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl_ipc
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    28672  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_realtek   114688  1
snd_soc_core          233472  2 snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          49152  0
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           86016  7 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  7 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek,dell_laptop
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    86016  12 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

## pulseaudio -v

I just killed and reran pulseaudio verbosely with `pulseaudio -k ; pulseaudio -v` and some messages seem interesting.

```
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)utils.c: could not open configuration file /usr/share/alsa/ucm/HDA Intel PCH at 0xdc328000 irq 133/HDA Intel PCH at 0xdc328000 irq 133.conf
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)parser.c: error: could not parse configuration for card HDA Intel PCH at 0xdc328000 irq 133
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)parser.c: uknown master file field pcm
I: [pulseaudio] (alsa-lib)parser.c: uknown master file field HDA-Intel
I: [pulseaudio] alsa-ucm.c: UCM available for card HDA Intel PCH
E: [pulseaudio] alsa-ucm.c: No UCM verb is valid for HDA Intel PCH
E: [pulseaudio] module-alsa-card.c: Failed to find a working profile.
E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_1f.3" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0 (alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3) failed to load module.
I: [pulseaudio] module-udev-detect.c: Found 1 cards.
```

Comment: Please show `lsof /dev/snd/*` and `lsmod |  grep snd` and almost forgot `ps -ef | grep pulse`

Comment: Thank you @nobody; I've added the outputs to the bottom of my question, together with potentially interesting `pulseaudio` errors (lines starting with `E:`).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat underwhelmingly here are the steps that completely
fixed sound for me, with two cold reboots (shutdown + turn the computer
back on manually) between every step.  Probably some of the restarts are not
useful.

- Upgrade the Linux kernel from version 4.15(?) to version 5.0.0
- Uninstall ALSA and pulseaudio (and all related packages I could find) through:

  ```
  sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio pavucontrol pulseaudio-utils
  ```
- Reinstall these packages:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils pulseaudio pavucontrol pulseaudio-utils
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me as well - I was beyond Linux 5.0 already so I skipped that step. Another tip on XPS 13 9350 - by default ubuntu discovered the internal WiFi card. Enable it- go into About -> Software updates and enable the prioritary driver. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqfy4.png)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1192676)

Answer (score 0):

There's similar reported pulseaudio errors of not detecting Realtek ALCxxx cards on other laptops, even on newer linux kernel like 5.18; so another alternative that works in some cases, is to disable ucm (as seen from pulseaudio -v log is enabled) by appending the following parameter/option in /etc/pulse/default.pa config file e.g.:

```
load-module module-udev-detect use_ucm=no
```

Of course after that computer should be restarted although a pulseaudio restart should suffice:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

See more details at [pulseaudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples#Disabling_UCM/%22HiFi%22) & [freedesktop](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pulseaudio/pulseaudio/-/issues/1268).